# salesforce.com functions Enable Test Space option is greyed out and unable to Turn it on in trial org of functions

Tags: salesforce-functions

Register for trial developer org for functions
go to set up > functions > Set Enable Test Space to TRUE.
Unable to set Enable test space to TRUE. the option is greyed out

Has anyone tried to enable this option Enable test space?

Comment: This option is likely meant for orgs which have a sandbox. We have that enabled in our regular production org. I don't think it is meant for dev orgs.

Comment: Enable Test Space
"Test Environments allow you to use Salesforce Functions with your Sandbox and Scratch orgs." but it also mentions scratch orgs. does this option enable it for scratch orgs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's greyed out (to the right) it means it is already enabled. On Trial Orgs it is enabled by default.

[image: Trial Space Already Enabled]